# Can ping google.com, but pinging 8.8.8.8 gives connect: network is unreachable

Tags: 18.04, dns

Yesterday I used my laptop connected to home network and everything worked just fine. Today when I tried to enter a site other than facebook or google I got communicate "Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.". On my phone I could connect to every site via my home network and when I connected to network hosted by my phone I also could connect every site on my laptop. So the problem was on line my computer - home network. I tried to ping google.com and 8.8.8.8 and the efect was as shown in topic. 
Everything is now fine, because I reset my router, but it's a bad solution, because I don't want to restart it everytime I have such a problem and would like a solid solution. Can anyone explain to me what possibly could cause that problem and what would be a proper way to deal with it?

I had this problem after installing ubuntu and if I remember correct setting DNS in "/etc/systemd/resolved.conf" solved the problem.

If more information is needed please ask, I will provide it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ask your router manufacturer, they'll likely have a better solution than us as I'm sure they're running some sort of proprietary software/drivers/who knows what else

Comment: 8.8.8.8 does not involve DNS resolution, so you probably turned off IPV4 and are using IPV6.

Comment: You could test for IPv6 connectivity with `ping -6 2001:4860:4860::8888` which is shown as the address for `nslookup google-public-dns-a.google.com`